# Not able to import package in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I installed the **Jodit Editor** using **npm -i jodit-react**. The package is added in the node modules but I am unable to import it.

This is is how I am importing the package **import JoditEditor from "../../node_modules/jodit-react/index";**

And this is the error I am getting: **Module not found: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/jodit-react/index'**

Screenshot of the error: [image: error picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
import JoditEditor from "../../node_modules/jodit-react/index";
```

To:

```
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react';
```

You can take a look at [this live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-gegqbf?file=components%2FExample.js,pages%2Findex.js) with Next.js

Comment: This is the error I am getting: error - ReferenceError: self is not defined

Comment: For the `ReferenceError: self is not defined` error, You need to wrap the component that you use JoditEditor and load it dynamically. See my example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-gegqbf?file=components%2FExample.js,pages%2Findex.js) for live working example.